# Using Laminar Data to return flight details by IATA ticket number

Tags: rest, api

I want to use the Laminar Data API to develop an app that allows users to enter an IATA flight number and receive detail about their flight, its position and status and so forth.

However, I can only seem to return flights by airline code, or by the specific flight ID via a separate API

```
https://api.laminardata.aero/v1/airlines/WZZ/flights?user_key=

https://api.laminardata.aero/v1/flights/9d43d6ca-e8ec-4fb2-b4c2-b39130902329?user_key=
```

Can I use these APIs to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the request pattern you would need to automate to achieve your desired outcome of a IATA flight number search using Laminar Data as the data source

If you already know the IATA number for a flight, the first two letters correspond to an IATA airlines code.

This can be converted to an ICAO airline code. You can use this code to call the Flights by Airline API which will return a trimmed down status report for all of the active flights for your chosen airline. One of the properties returned is the 'iataFlightNumber' - look for the iataFlightNumber that matches the flight you are interested in.

You can take the GUFI  from the above flight and query the FlightsbyGUFI API to get a detailed look at the flight.